# How to create a Java program that plays WAV files based off of text?

Tags: java, eclipse, wav

I am wondering on how to play a WAV file when certain text is written. For example, the program would play a WAV file when I type hello into a box. I am wondering how to do this, if it is even possible. Thanks!

Comment: What would it play? A file named hello.wav that is already in a specific location? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: There will be a folder with a wav file named 1.wav, and when I type hello into a box, the file will play.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your question:

1. How do I play an audio file through java?
2. How do I get and check the text of a textfield?

For the first, this bit of code [[source]](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~illah/CLASSDOCS/javasound.pdf) will do:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
try {
    AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(new URL(“file://c:/blah/foo.wav”));
    clip.play();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Just replace the url path with the location and name of the .WAV you want to play.

For the second, You're going to want a JFrame with a JTextField in it that checks the value of the text upon hitting enter, and if it is equal to "hello", call the above play-wav-file code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class WavBox extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField textField;
    private static final String KEY = "hello";

    public WavBox() {

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(textField.getText().equals(KEY)){
                    System.out.println("Good Key");
                    //Do your .wav playing here.
                }
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new WavBox();
    }
}
```